# MySql - Update para null coluna unique

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde galera.

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de realizar um `UPDATE` para `NULL` onde o campo permita somente valores `UNIQUE`.

Tentei dessa forma:

```
update FUNCIONARIO set codigocartao = NULL where situacao = 'DESATIVADO'
```

Mas me retornou o erro de registro duplicado.

O cenário que eu preciso é:  o campo codigocartao deve ter registro único,  mas também pode ser nulo.
o cenário que tenho hoje é: toda vez que preciso setar o campo para `NULL`, eu acabo tendo que deletar o funcionario da tabela.

Estou fazendo algo errado ou essa possibilidade não existe no `MySQL`?
Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Em teoria é possível pq um nulo nunca é igual a outro. `codigocartao` é FK também? poderia colocar a mensagem original do erro? e definição da tabela.

Comment: rray, não, o campo estava definido com UNIQUE e NOT NULL (este o problema). obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode fazer isso. veja a  [documentação MySQL (versão 5.5)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE  index allows multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

Verifique se você não definiu a coluna como NOT NULL

Comment: Renato, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: A coluna estava definica como NOT NULL, este estava sendo o problema

Comment: Então é isso, resolvido ;)